# Why my communication site is missing "Term store management" inside the site setting

Tags: sharepoint-online, term-store, communication-site

I have created a new communication modern online site collection, buy inside its site setting i can not find the "Term store management" + when i tried to create a new managed metadta column i can not link it to any term set.

here are 2 screen shots:-

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable the below two features to see the **term store management**.

```
   Enable-SPFeature -id "73EF14B1-13A9-416b-A9B5-ECECA2B0604C" -Url <your communication site url >

   Enable-SPFeature -id "7201D6A4-A5D3-49A1-8C19-19C4BAC6E668" -Url <your communication site url>
```

**Note** :

- Execute the above two commands in the sample test communication site, if it gives successful result, execute in the actual site.

Comment: what are those features?

Comment: Term store management in site collection and site level

Comment: First create a sample test communication site and run the above two commands, then if successful run in the actual site

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable the missing feature using PnP PowerShell:

```
connect-pnponline https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/communication
Enable-PnPFeature 73EF14B1-13A9-416b-A9B5-ECECA2B0604C -Scope Site -Force
```